# How do I design a SQL query that will show me all users who visited at least one page for the last 20 out of 24 hours?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

In order to identify human traffic (as opposed to crawlers, bots, etc), I would like to design an SQL query that will identify all unique visitor ID's that have visited websites in the last 20 of 24 hours (as most humans would not be browsing for that long). I believe I understand how I want to structure it, "How many UNIQUE hours have any activity for each visitor in the past 24 hours, and WHERE 20 hours have at least some activity".

While the specifics of such a query would depend on the tables involved, I'm having trouble understanding if my structure is on the right track:

```
SELECT page_url, affinity, num
FROM (
 SELECT AGG GROUP BY visitor_id, pages.page_url, max(v.max_affinity) as affinity, COUNT(*) as num, Row_Number()
   OVER (Partition By v.visitor_id ORDER BY COUNT(visitor_id) DESC) AS RowNumber
 FROM audience_lab_active_visitors v
 SELECT pages ON pages.p_date >= '2017-09-14'
 WHERE v.p_date='2017-09-14'
 GROUP BY v.vispage_visitors, pages.page_url
) tbl WHERE RowNumber < 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your query is valid SQL, but I have an idea of what you're trying to accomplish. Rather than use a static date, I filtered by the past 24 hours and truncated the current timestamp to the hour, otherwise the query would be considering 25 unique hours. I also removed `page_url` from the query since it didn't seem relevant to the results based on what you're trying to solve.

For each `visitor_id`, the query counts the number of unique hours recorded based on the column (`timestamp_col` in this example) used to record the timestamp of the page view. `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('hour', timestamp_col)) < 20` returns those you've identified at humans, meaning they visited the website up to 19 of the past 24 hours.

```
SELECT
  visitor_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('hour', timestamp_col)) AS num,
  MAX(v.max_affinity) AS affinity
FROM audience_lab_active_visitors AS v
  JOIN pages AS p ON v.page_url = p.page_url
WHERE
  v.p_date >= DATE_TRUNC('hour', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - INTERVAL '24' hour
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('hour', timestamp_col)) < 20;
```